# How to get all the values that are from the same property we just defined from the first request to use in the next request jmeter?

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, jmeter

I use Regular Expression and JSR223 PostProcessor in the first thread. This is my Regular Expression:

[image]

This is my JSR223 PostProcessor:

```
${__setProperty(npwp,${__property(npwp)})}; // Define NPWP variable
```

And I use SOAP/XML-RPC Request in the second thread:

[image]

and I use `${__property(npwp)}` to get the value of npwp.

How to get all the values that are from the same property if I I set the first and the second thread group with `Number of Thread = 2`?

Comment: What is the expected output to be?  [A,B]? A,B ? Object?

Comment: the output should be A,B. I already found the solution and I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution of my question:

- Use **Property** not Variable because **Variable is local to thread**
- Check **Run Thread Groups Consecutively (run groups one at a time)** in Test Plan

[image]

Because If you don’t check it, it will still use the value from the previous Execution/Run and Sometimes it may happen that Thread Group 2 will run before Thread Group 1, so the variables for Thread Group 2 are not set.

Then define the Test Plan:

- Thread Group 1

  - SOAP/XML-RPC Request

    - Regular Expression Extractor
    - JSR223 PostProcessor
    - Counter
  - Debug Sampler
- Thread Group 2

  - SOAP/XML-RPC Request

    - Regular Expression Extractor
    - JSR223 PostProcessor
    - Counter
  - Debug Sampler

Here is the detail of every test plan:

- set Number of Threads (users) = 3 in Thread Group 1 and Thread Group 2

[image]

- set property npwp `${__property(npwp${counter})}` in SOAP/XML-RPC Request

[image]

- set Regular Expression Extractor

[image]

- set JSR223 PostProcessor

[image]

- set Counter

[image]

- The Result

[image]

- Npwp 1: 48482

[image]

- Npwp 2: 54270

[image]

- Npwp 3: 48454

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables in form of `${something}` in Groovy scripts as:

1. It is not safe as Function or Variable may result into some Groovy code which might do something you don't want
2. It clashes with [Groovy Templates](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html) therefore you won't be able to use it anywhere
3. It breaks [Groovy killer script compilation and caching feature](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) making your script performance a big question mark
4. Your __setProperty() function code is not correct, it should be something like:

   ```
    ${__setProperty(npwp,${npwp},)}
   ```
5. If you want Groovy-only way the relevant code will be something like:

   ```
   props.put('npwp', vars.get('npwp'))
   ```

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.